# make file multiple executables

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a folder called UnitTest. I have several .c files in it. All files contain function 'main'.

Using makefile, I want to compile all .c files of that folder together.
But these files have dependency on other C files which are in different folder.

How can I write make file for this?

eg.
Common\*.c - generate object file
App\*.c - generate object file. - refers to *.o files of Common directory
UnitTest\*.c - these files should be compiled as executables. Refer *.o from directory App and Common.

Update:
Header files are in seperate directory called \Include

I need a single makefile for this. Please help.

Comment: Do you use header files? Where are they?

Comment: @Beta, Header files are in seperate directory called \Include

Comment: And for each file in `UnitTest/`, do you know which files in `Common/` and `Apps/` it needs?

Comment: Any files of Common or Apps are needed. In future user can define Macros in Common folder files. or More source code will come in App folder, which we have to test from UnitTest folders.

Comment: Then you had better build libraries. Are you familiar with those?

Comment: Yes. *.so files, right?

Answer (score 2):

As per the standards every directory will contain one Makefile. So you can have three Makefiles for this job done if you have three directories.

```
(d) common
 |
 |---(f) common.h
 |---(f) common.c
 |---(f) Makefile --- MAkefile for the common folder.

(d) app
 |
 |---(f) app.h
 |---(f) app.c
 |---(f) Makefile

(d) unittest
 |
 |---(f) unittest.h
 |---(f) unittest.c
 |---(f) Makefile

(f) Makefile --- invoke all makefiles in the mentioned order.
```

If you want one Makefile to happen all these done, you can do in that way also. Here you have to compile the files by providing paths of the files. order is most impotent.

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated, so we will take it in stages. First, building the object files:

```
CFLAGS += -I/include

vpath %.h /include
```

This should be enough to build any object file in `Common/`, `Apps/` or `UnitTest/`. **Test this before going further.**

Now to build all of the objects in `Common/`:

```
COMMONSOURCES := $(wildcard Common/*.c)
COMMONOBJECTS := $(COMMONSOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(COMMONOBJECTS)
```

**Test this before going further.**

Remove that `all` rule, and put in a rule for the Common library. (We'll use a static library for now, since it's a little simpler.)

```
Common/libCommon.a: $(COMMONOBJECTS)
    ar -cvq $@ $^
```

Test that much, tell us in the comments how it worked, then we'll build `Apps` library and the `UnitTest` executables.